# Use existing crystal Report with a new dataset

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

I am trying to bind my crystal report that is already created meaning  I have the `.rpt` file.  Now I am adding this to my application using Add- reports - existing item.  This report is created based on a  oracle table view.  in my program I have created a dynamic dataset that has all the fields required for this report.  now I need to find a way to use this existing `.rpt` file and parse my data from dataset to create a report in `pdf` format.
 I know how to export the report into `pdf`.  But I don't know how to use this `.rpt` file and parse my dataset data through it.

Here is the code I have so far

```
using System;
using  System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Data;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;


namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        OracleConnection connection;
        OracleDataAdapter OracleAdapter;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string firstSql = null;
       // string secondSql = null;

        connetionString = "blah blah
        firstSql = "select * from STATEMENT_DomESTIC";
       // secondSql = "Select * from DOM_DETAILS";
        connection = new OracleConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OracleAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(firstSql, connection);
            OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "domestic_header");
            OracleAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = secondSql;
            OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "domestic_detail");
            OracleAdapter.Dispose();
            connection.Close();

           // GridView1.DataSource = ds;
           // GridView1.DataBind();


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
    }
}
}
```

I Did research on this but, was unable to find a good example where this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `ReportDocument` object supplied by Crystal. For example...

```
ReportDocument reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
reportDoc.Load("YourReportName");  //or path to your report
reportDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Does this do what you are looking for?

Comment: This got me started. Thanks Ill let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Sure, I have been working with the Crystal .NET API a lot lately myself. Definitely has been a learning process. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I did what you said and than added export option to export the report to pdf.  but I am not getting anywhere with it. I get error stating database logon failed.  but I am not using database as a source.   the  reportDoc.SetDataSource(ds);  changes the datasoruce to dataset?  am I correct ? if so  it should not throw an error of not connecting to database